# NodeJS Request Upload Image

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, request

Trying to upload an image using nodejs, express & request module but keep getting 415 from Amazon S3 instance.

```
    fs.createReadStream(req.files.image.path).pipe(request.post(defaults.url, {
        form: {
            param_1: '',
            param_2: ''
        }
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error){
            callback(error, null);
        }else{

            if(response.statusCode === 200){

                callback({}, body);

            }else{

                callback(body, response);
            }


        }
    }));
```

I think the image is not getting appended on the request but i'm not 100%. Any advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pipe expects a Writable stream as parameter. you can use res object of express directly as the pipe destination. But if you like to upload to s3, you can read the file from req stream and use putObject to write it to s3

```
var fs = require ('fs')
fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {

    var AWS = require('./aws_config')
    var s3 = new AWS.S3()
    var bucket =  ''
    s3.putObject({
      ACL: 'public-read', // by default private access
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: file_name,
      Body: data
    }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.send(500, {msg: 'image upload failed', error: err})
      } else {
        console.log('S3 upload Successful')

        res.send({})
      }
});
```

If you like to download you can use pipe to redirect the read object to response directly

```
app.get('/download/:file', function(req, res, next) {
  var AWS = require('./aws_config')
  var s3 = new AWS.S3()
  s3.getObject({
    Bucket: '',
    Key: req.params.file 
  }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log (err)
    var fs = require ('fs')
    var filePath = __dirname + "/downloads/" + req.params.file
    fs.writeFile(filePath, data.Body, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      else {
        res.attachment(filePath) 
        var filestream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        filestream.pipe(res);
        // TODO: delete file from server ? 
      }
    });    
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks Kamrul, your code works but I was looking to avoid using the aws apis. I managed to get it working with form-data plugin.

Comment: @kamrul I tried the same code, am getting a error a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined".I am using restify.js framework.

Comment: @vivek, can you please check whether the `req` object processed by express contains `files`. otherwise check your express multi-part setting.

Comment: @Kamrul sorry.. i am using restify.js framework not express, so problem with restify, can you help on this.

Comment: @vivekP, if you can put your problem as a separate problem and explain where you got the error, i can try to help you out.