# Nodejitsu file system and static files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cloud, nodejitsu

When using nodejitsu as hosting how can you store a few user uploads? I know the space is limited but my question is how can you backup those files saved when the file system is not persistent and every time I upload a newer version I lose them? What architecture is suggested for such usage? Do I need to create a static file server, use a cloud based solution like aws s3 or something else? I've tried downloading the tar for the current active version but any files created by users are not downloaded as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use nodejitsu and I use S3 to handle file uploads.

It's really easy to set it up.

Relevant post: [NodeJS Request Upload Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577869/nodejs-request-upload-image)

Code:

```
var fs = require ('fs')
fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {

    var AWS = require('./aws_config')
    var s3 = new AWS.S3()
    var bucket =  ''
    s3.putObject({
      ACL: 'public-read', // by default private access
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: file_name,
      Body: data
    }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.send(500, {msg: 'image upload failed', error: err})
      } else {
        console.log('S3 upload Successful')

        res.send({})
      }
});
```

Comment: I was afraid so... It's not the how to upload that concerns me but I wanted to avoid aws but still use nodejitsu...